# capture json value returned from controller into a variable in asp.net mvc view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm developing an application using MVC/Jquery, i able to get a value from controller to view by below getJson code,

```
 $.getJSON('@Url.Action("SampleData", "Home")', { pageNum: 1, pageSize: PageSize, accountDetailsType: AccountDetailsType }, function (result) {
            //total number of records
            totalRecords = result.total;
            //total records
            records = result.data;

            $('#Description').val(result.reportType);
```

`$('#Description')` gives me desired data, which i can check by below textbox in view,

```
@Html.TextBox("Description")
```

now, question is, is there any way to put this value in any variable/hidden filed, so that base on that value..i can show/hide some control in my view...

similar like,

```
if(("Description") = "VB")
{
}
else
{

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please use the {} button to format your code the next time. I've added additional relevant tags as well.

Comment: Do you want to access the same data which returned from getJSON ? you are already doing it using $("#Description"). Why do you want to copy the information in another variable/hidden field?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see no need for putting the result into a hidden field. You can directly hide or show the affected controls in the callback function of your Ajax request:

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("SampleData", "Home")',
    { pageNum: 1, pageSize: PageSize, accountDetailsType: AccountDetailsType },
    function (result) {
        //total number of records
        totalRecords = result.total;
        //total records
        records = result.data;

        if (result.reportType == "VB") {
          $('#control1').hide();
          $('#control2').show();
        } else {
          $('#control1').show();
          $('#control2').hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: +1 - bonus pointer, you can turn those 6 lines of hide/show into about 2 by using `.toggle` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change following line

```
@Html.TextBox("Description")
```

to

```
@Html.Hidden("Description")
```

you can set value of this hidden field like

```
$("#Description").val(result.reportType);
```

and read it like

```
var somevar = $("#Description").val(); //assign to variable or make comparisons
```